# How to upload animated webp files in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, webp, animated-webp

I want to upload animated webp files (animation in WebP format instead of GIF.) not like traditional gif file because it is much more compact in size.
Although I found a way to upload webp images and it is uploading without any problem but when I am trying to add animated webp file i am getting error although both files formats are same but still images are being uploaded but not the animated ones.

Getting this error:
The server cannot process the image. This can happen if the server is busy or does not have enough resources to complete the task. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2560 pixels.

Although it irrelevant error I have checked the file size and everything given in it.

Comment: _"I have checked the file size"_ - the size suggestion from the error message was not about file size, but pixel dimensions. To be able to _modify_ an image (like when creating different sized versions/ thumbnails), the image data needs to be unpacked - so that is about width * height * 4 bytes already it will take in RAM, for a static image. And with an animated image, that will increase, with the number of frames.

Answer (score 0):

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 180
```

And also try this if you are using WordPress:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```